# Titanium Extracting first 10 secs of audio from Ti.MediaSound Object

Tags: iphone, mobile, titanium, audio-recording, audio-player

I need to extract first Ten(10) secs from an audio file.

We have the following code.

```
var file = recording.stop(); 
sound = Titanium.Media.createSound({sound:file});
```

I need to extract first 10 seconds from sound object.

How we can do this?

Also, How to merge two sound objects.

ex:

`sound1` has 10 secs and `sound2` has 15secs.

I want `sound3` which is `sound1 + sound2`,

which should play both `sound1` and `sound2` continuously.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var sound = Ti.Media.createSound({
    sound: file,
    duration: 10
});
```

That will get you the first 10 seconds of the `sound` however even with the `looping` set to `true` you will need to create your own custom timers to alternate between the sounds playing.

Comment: Thanks Brain for the quick reply.

Comment: I need to know how we can concatenate two sound objects?

Comment: And you have to do it one the phone, you can't do it on the desktop?